# How can I sum a bit column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a view as follows:

```
select t1.PID,t2.*,1 AccessCount 
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Here, `AccessCount` column's data type is considered as '`int`' by default by SQL server.

But when i apply sum operator on that column, it is saying **Sum operator can't be applied on bit type of operand1** and this is not reproducible on all server systems.

Is there any impact of server system configuration on the query execution?

Comment: What does server configuration have to do with a clear query error message? Besides, there is no "by default" type. If the error says the type is bit, the type is bit. Post the *actual* query and table schemas. The view doesn't help at all. If the behaviour is different from one server to another, it means the *tables* are different

Comment: This query, *as given*, can *never* yield an error of the kind you describe, because it does not contain `SUM`. And `SELECT 1 AccessCount` will *always* yield a column of type `INT` and never a `BIT`, so simply wrapping it in a `SUM` will do nothing either. Post the actual code that's causing you trouble, and the way you're accessing the results. With a view, always try calling `sp_refreshview` first to ensure the metadata isn't out of date.

Comment: Re "Is there any impact of server system configuration on the query execution?": I am not aware of any settings / that would affect this. The cause is some difference between your queries on different systems.

Answer (score 3):

```
U can use these three methods  
    DECLARE @TEST TABLE (GROUP_ID INTEGER, STATUS BIT)
    INSERT INTO @TEST
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1



    SELECT
            SUM(CAST(STATUS AS INT)) AS '1ST METHOD',
            SUM(CASE(STATUS) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2ND METHOD',
            COUNT(NULLIF(STATUS,0)) AS '3RD METHOD'
    FROM 
            @TEST
```

Comment: can  u use these quries

Answer (score 2):

Run below mentioned query to resolve your issue.

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, AccessCount)) FROM Table1
```

This query will first convert the value into int and then SUM all the values of the column.